# Calibrator error "Failed to execute calibrator, or an error occurred during calibration."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, data-quality-services

I am using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
>   Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

And I got this error... "Failed to execute calibrator, or an error occurred during calibration."

What can I do about this error? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: am I the only one using this product, I posted a couple of DQS questions the last month and I receive no answers in all the forums!